# SharePoint Online Promoted State for Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, newsfeed

Working in an online teamsite and trying to get a handle on the new modern pages in the site pages library.

I noticed that New > Page, News Post, and News Link all end up as pages in the site pages library. I was trying to figure out how to tell them apart and found [this thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Change-News-Page-to-Site-Page/m-p/181257) talking about the **Promoted State** modern column -- you can find it from the view Add Column > Show/Hide menu, but not from the classic Library Properties. It says that regular Site Pages have a value of 0 and that News pages have a value of 2.

I've googled quite a bit, but have not found much else about the column or how it works.

**First question:** Does anybody know of MS documentation for this column and what values can be used? For example what is a 1 or an 8?

I also tried to change the value by first adding it to a view and then using Quick Edit to change it. However the cell remains greyed out and does not allow for changes. I'm site collection admin and have full control on this team site, so shouldn't be the issue. My guess is that when the above thread was created several months ago that it was an editable column and in an update since they locked it down, but that is just a guess?

**Second question:** Has anybody else tried (recently) to change the value of a Promoted State successfully? Or is there some other way you know to change it?

Comment: Has anyone been successful in turning a promoted state from 0 to 1?

Comment: Never found a way.  But I found a workaround.  If you add a choice column to the page library, named, oh, say, "Category" and set the ones you want to show as news to "news" - then you can filter the news so it only displays news with the category set.  That way you can sort of unpublish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit the Promoted State there is a easy way and I just found that just go to the Promoted state column --> Column settings --> edit ---> Don't change anything just save the column and now that Promoted can be found in the page details where the field will be editable and Hope this helps for everyone out there.

However, if you do this then the FirstPublishedDate field will not work correctly for newly-published pages on your site--it will not get set, and all these pages will have a default value of January 1st.

Comment: That is brilliant. I had to add it to a list view to get the Column Settings menu and then like magic it was there.

Comment: @Rothrock Could you please test when you create a site page using a template ideally site page should show a Promoted state for 0 but it shows 2 after this change and do you know why?

Comment: It is working just fine for me. New Pages get 1 or 2 and regular page gets 0. Just like I would expect. Did you accidently set a default for the column or something like that?

Comment: Yes I see a default value set to zero in the column settings @Rothrock

Answer (score 4):

The numbers used for now are 0, 1 and 2

0 is a published 'site page' that is NOT considered 'News' and does not end up in the news roll up (ie, your home page)

1 is a news page that is not published yet

2 is a news page that is published or a news link (from the News roll up + button)

It is confusing since the news page and the site page have the same content type (Site Page)

I have never tried to change the number, however if you have just published the page (ie = 2) you can unpublish it so it will become 1. Switching from a news page (1 or 2) to 0 is more difficult.

It is true that in the very beginning you had only one type of page that used to go equally in the news roll up and in the highlighted content and it was later split to have pages that can only be rolled up in the news roll.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you have a source for this or somewhere to check if/as they make changes to this?

Comment: the source is my personal testing

Comment: I guess there's no way to "unpromote" a page?  Once you've promoted a page, is there no way to return it to the state of just a site page without it being news?

Answer (score 1):

This might help too:
I can't seem to be able to change the promoted state from SharePoint, but I can from SharePoint Designer. In SPD open the page and click "Edit file".

Then you can do a search (Ctrl+F) for "Promoted", or find this line and simply change the number to one of the ones mentioned by Susan above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a site that was created from who knows what template, but I was also facing the same problem.  I could add the Promoted State column using the add/hide columns method but it was set to read only in Grid View edit mode. Then I thought perhaps I could access the aspx file of the page directly via Windows Explorer.  I pasted in the URL (e.g. "https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com/sites/YourSitePath/SitePages" to the Site Pages library and voila - there were my pages.

[image]

Right click and edit in Notepad++, search for "Promoted" (2nd hit for me) and find this line:

<mso:PromotedState msdt:dt="string">2.00000000000000</mso:PromotedState>

Change to:
<mso:PromotedState msdt:dt="string">0.00000000000000</mso:PromotedState>

Save the file and BAM.  No more News.